# Making objects iterable?

Tags: python, class, iterable

I'm trying to iterate over each row in a list of lists, append an element from each row to a new list, then find the unique elements in the new list.

I understand that I can do this easily with a for loop. I'm trying a different route because I want to learn more about classes and functions.

Here's an example of the list of lists. The first row is the header:

```
legislators = [
 ['last_name', 'first_name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'type', 'state', 'party'],
 ['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration'],
 ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', '', 'rep', 'VA', ''],
 ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', '', 'rep', 'SC', ''],
 ['Carroll', 'Daniel', '1730-07-22', 'M', 'rep', 'MD', ''],
 ['Clymer', 'George', '1739-03-16', 'M', 'rep', 'PA', ''],
 ['Contee', 'Benjamin', '', 'M', 'rep', 'MD', ''],...]
```

Here's my code:

```
import csv
f = open("legislators.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
legislators = list(csvreader)

class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.header = data[0] #Isolate header from CSV file
        self.data = data[1:] #Subset CSV data to remove header

legislators_dataset = Dataset(legislators)

def the_set_maker(dataset):
    gender = []
    for each in dataset:
        gender.append(each[3])
    return set(gender)

t=the_set_maker(legislators_dataset)
print(t)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d65cb459931b> in <module>()
     20     return set(gender)
     21
---> 22 t=the_set_maker(legislators_dataset)
     23 print(t)

<ipython-input-1-d65cb459931b> in the_set_maker(dataset)
     16 def the_set_maker(dataset):
     17     gender = []
---> 18     for each in dataset:
     19         gender.append(each[3])
     20     return set(gender)

TypeError: 'Dataset' object is not iterable
```

I think the answer is to try to create a method using `def __iter__(self)` in my `Dataset` class, but I haven't been able to get this to work. Is this the right track? If not, what's a better one?

Comment: To make an object *iterable*, it needs to implement `__iter__`, which must return an *iterator*, i.e., an object that implements `__iter__` **and** `__next__`. Iterator `__iter__` methods should simply return `self`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. I'll look into __next__. Can you demonstrate how to use __next__ and __iter__ in my code?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a duplicate of that. You answered "How do I make my class iterable" with "what is an iterable," which requires at least one or two logical jumps to implement. I've reopened.

Comment: You should be able the get the behavior you're looking for by defining your iter method as **return iter(self.data)**. Alternatively, take a look at making a Pandas DataFrame out of your CSV file (or out of the list objects), and reference the column by name instead

Comment: What's more, with the detail in the question, I feel like this can generate a useful answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith check out the second dupe target, "Build a basic Python iterator".

Comment: @TroubleZero uh, that is totally wrong. All built-in container types are iterable in Python - heck, even many non-container types are iterable (e.g. file objects). Also, your class should't "return data[1:]", whatever that means. Rather, you *should make your class iterable*, which might involve simply delegating to `iter(self.data)`

Comment: Just an aside, you can do `self.header, *self.data = data`...

Comment: @JonClements That's very cool, I never knew you could do that in an assignment. Great suggestion

Comment: As a minor suggestion, you can also improve your set_maker function using a set comprehension: `return {each[3] for each in dataset}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

> This method should return a new iterator object that can iterate over all the objects in the container.

You might try the following class definition:

```
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.header = data[0] #Isolate header from CSV file
        self.data = data[1:] #Subset CSV data to remove header

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
```

If you're open to trying new options, consider using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('legislators.csv')
t=df['gender']
```

Or, if you really want to read in the CSV yourself,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(legislators[1:], columns=legislators[0])
```

Comment: The `pandas` seems irrelevant. Regardless, the `csv` module is just fine...

Comment: True, it's irrelevant to learning how to make objects iterable. In the specific case given, though, he mentioned wanting to get specific elements out of each row, in which case `numpy` or (since we have labeled columns) `pandas` is ideal for the purpose

Comment: ... so is the standard library `csv` and it doesn't require the heavy, heavy, `numpy`/`pandas` dependancy just to grab data from a column in a csv file.

Comment: I was able to get the code to work- thank you all for your help and for the alternative ideas, especially the DataFrame. As you can see, I'm new to all of this, so I really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you'll need to implement `__iter__` in `class Dataset`. Note that this is actually the `set(...)` call that's throwing the error, since it iterates through your class to enumerate the set elements.

Luckily your set elements are likely just `Dataset.data`, which makes this easy to write `Dataset.__iter__`.

```
class Dataset(object):
    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self)
```

I would point out, however, that your `the_set_maker` function seems a little too specialized to be top-level. It's also a bit trivial, since it's literally `set([el[3] for el in container])`. I would put this in `Dataset` as well.

```
class Dataset(object):
    ...

    def to_set(self):
        return set([el[3] for el in self.data])
        # Note that this throws away your header!
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I agree that the function is trivial- I'm trying to use classes and functions even if they are trivial so that I can become more comfortable with them, so I appreciate your example of how I can incorporate the function into the class!

Answer (score -2):

you need to change a little

```
class Dataset:
    i = 0

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.header = data[0] #Isolate header from CSV file
        self.data = data[1:] #Subset CSV data to remove header

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        if self.i < len(self.data):
            self.i += 1
            return self.data[self.i-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: This is incorrectly implemented, you don't need *both `.next` and `__next__`*, the former is Python 2, the latter is Python 3, don't mix them.

Comment: Also, this makes `Dataset` an *iterator*, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: That's fine, I suppose, if you want to write code that is runnable on Python 2/3, but the main issue here is that you've made `Dataset` an *iterator*, not merely *iterable*, which is not a good practice. Consider all the built-in container types, `list`, `tuple`, `set` etc - these return specialized iterator objects from `iter`, not themselves. The *iterators* return themselves.

Comment: Also, you've made `i` a *class variable*, then *shadow it with an instance variable*, not really what you want, and can lead to subtle bugs...

Comment: @Yuriy Arhipov I appreciate the help- like the answer I selected, it's a bit beyond me, but that's good.